# No submit button available when using Display Suite Forms to render a node add form

Tags: theming, forms, display-suite

I've created a Display Suite layout and assigned it to my content type.

Everything else is rendered just fine on the form but there's just a "small" problem: **no submit button.**

Do I need to use some special variables in template file to render submit button?

Current template is(nothign):

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="well-success well-sm well col col-sm-12 col-md-2 bg-success text-center">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-10 well-sm well">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="col col-md-4">

          <?php print $row_first_col_first; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-md-4">

          <?php print $row_first_col_second; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-md-4">

          <?php print $row_first_col_third; ?>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="well-success well-sm well col col-sm-12 col-md-2 bg-success text-center">
      <h1>2</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-10 well-sm well">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col col-md-7">

          <?php print $row_second_col_first; ?>
        </div>


        <div class="col col-md-4">
          <?php print $row_second_col_second; ?>

          <?php print $row_second_col_third; ?>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="well-success well-sm well col col-sm-12 col-md-2 bg-success text-center">
      <h1>3</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-10 well-sm well">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col col-md-4">

          <?php print $row_third_col_first; ?></div>

          <div class="col col-md-4">

            <?php print $row_third_col_second; ?></div>
            <div class="col col-md-4">

              <?php print $row_third_col_third; ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in time. Went through the ds form source code and found a variable drupal_render_children which holds the so far "unrendered" part of form.

So instead of using regular drupal_render_children as function and passing form etc for it you use it just as an variable.